# android app for sending mail using lotus notes server(dominoes server)

Tags: android, lotus-domino, lotus

I need to create an android app for sending a push mail using lotus notes server( dominoes server). it means I need to use the client for sending mail as lotus notes, but I don't want  to install lotus notes traveller. Is there any way of sending mail using dominoes server email id through an android app.( I want to send a standard message everytime). I need to create something like an android app which would send a standard message using my lotus notes mail id

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28826284/sending-mail-to-lotus-domino-server-from-android-without-notes-traveller-install

Comment: The old question is on hold. I edited the title last night to try and clarify it.  Please see my comments on the original question, and try to clarify it so it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to understand and probably do not belong to Stack Overflow as it does not seem to be a code related issue. you should try Super User forum instead

Do you want to route an email from your app through the domino server to a recipient outside your domino organisation?

if so, then you need to setup your server to allow SMTP mailrouting/relay from you app. you can setup the SMTP to send an email using a username/password

You setup SMTP in the configuration document on your server.

Comment: He says he's creating an app, so this is not a SuperUser question. As I interpret it, he wants his mobile app to be able to send messages to Notes/Domino users, but he doesn't want to install Traveller. (Installing traveller wouldn't really help.)  I put  a comment on the version of his question that he posted yesterday indicating that the answer really depends on what ports are open on the Domino server. He can just send an SMTP message, or maybe use the REST API to drop a message in mail.box.